# Textview in item with 9-patch image background has incorrect position

Tags: android, listview, textview, nine-patch

I created a 9-patch image which serves as the background of my listview items. I noticed that the text was vertically moved to the start of the vertical patching which I also designated in red on the next image:

[image]

It is plausible that the scaling patch will be started there because I dont want the arrow to be scaled. However, this seems to have an effect to the vertical location of the textview. A negative margin doesnt work, I would like to put the textview up, how can I solve this?

Comment: You need to set proper padding, the right and bottom lines in 9-patch image.

Comment: I am not that familiar with 9-patch images, could you explain how to set the padding in a 9patch image?

Comment: Oh I think I forgot to set the fill area of the image...

Answer (score 2):

For the future users that can get to this question.
Top and Left parts are stretchable area, this part will grow when the item needs to grow.

Bottom and Right parts are the fill area, your content will reside in this part only, the rest is something like the padding.

[image]